# how to bold a label in zend form element

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, php

hi i am using zend form , i want to

> bold one of the labels  , this is my element's code

```
    $od = new Zend_Form_Element_MultiCheckbox('od');        
    $od->setLabel(' Add Occupancy Denominations : ');
    $od->class = 'od';
    $od->addMultiOptions($options['od']);
    if (isset($options['od_vals'])) { //value set in edit room type
        $od->setValue($options['od_vals']);
    }   
    $od->setDecorators(
                         array(
                              array('ViewHelper',
                                        array('helper' => 'formMultiCheckbox')
                            ),
                            array('Label',
                                        array('class' => 'label')
                            ),
                            array('HtmlTag',
                                        array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'formfield')
                            ),
                         )
                      );
```

i want to bold

> Add Occupancy Denominations :

like this

> **Add Occupancy Denominations :**

how can i do this . please help  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, usually, you can gain that effect through the CSS rule.

```
.zend_form dt label {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

But that's of course if you keep the default decorators.

Comment: i added                            array('Label',
                                        array('class' => 'label bold')
                            ),
class bold to label ,  in css  .bold {font-weight:bold; }